# “” value has an invalid format. It must be in the format of YYYY MM DD HH:MM

Tags: django, django-models

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.timezone import now

class recommend(models.Model):
            sno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
            comment= models.TextField()
            user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            timestamp= models.DateTimeField(default=now) 
            def __str__(self):
                            return self.recommend[0:20] + "..." + "by" + self.user.username
```

**error**

```
importing signals
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, apps, auth, blog, contenttypes, home, sessions, verify_email, videos
Running migrations:
Applying home.0004_alter_contactme_timestamp...Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/storage/emulated/0/imaginecode/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "/storage/emulated/0/imaginecode/manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 244, in handle
post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
 state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
 state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 227, in apply_migration
 state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 126, in apply
operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 244, in database_forwards
schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 140, in alter_field
super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 608, in alter_field
self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 362, in _alter_field
self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 202, in _remake_table
'default': self.quote_value(self.effective_default(new_field))
 File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 324, in effective_default
return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 842, in get_db_prep_save
return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1427, in get_db_prep_value
value = self.get_prep_value(value)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1406, in get_prep_value
value = super().get_prep_value(value)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1266, in get_prep_value
return self.to_python(value)
File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1388, in to_python
raise exceptions.ValidationError(django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

Actually first i had wrote **blank=True** in timestamp field but it didn't work and after that i tried **null=True** and then, i runned makemigrations and then, it asked me to enter default value in terminal and i had written **" "**. After it is showing me this error even if i have changed the default value. Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete your your migrations folder then once again run *makemigrations* followed by *migrate* . It should work.

Comment: Please can you tell me where i can find migrations folder ?

Comment: I have finded that folder  Is i have to delete the migrations for one app or for whole project

Comment: You can just delete migrations folder of app level then run makemigrations appname followed by migrate appname

Comment: First of all run "python manage.py makemigrations app_name" then shows.

Comment: I have done it. Thanks a lot. I also have one other question. Can you help me with it?

Comment: Sure, no worries

Comment: This is link of question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69140961/16575357

Comment: if you want to connect here is my linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/prem-tamang-534645198/