# How to send verification email in django

Tags: django, django-views

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, logout as userlogout, login as userlogin


def signup(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    username=request.POST['username']
    firstname=request.POST['firstname']
    lastname=request.POST['lastname']
    email=request.POST['email']
    password=request.POST['password1']
    if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() :
        messages.error(request, "Username already exists.")
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])       
        
    elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        messages.error(request,"An account already exists with this email.")
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    else:
        myuser = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        myuser.first_name= firstname
        myuser.last_name= lastname
        myuser.save()
        messages.success(request, " Your account has been successfully created.")
        return redirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

I have to send verification email after signup. I have some methods but it didn't work because it works on forms which is created by django but i have own created form in html and get all the data and then saved it with above method. Has someone have any idea how to send verification email.

Comment: Is it a verification email or a welcome email? Your question reads "Verification" but your email body does not say so. If it is verification email you have to generate tokens and use them in confirmation url.

Comment: I have not email body. It is views.py

Comment: Refer this. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/django-sign-up-and-login-with-confirmation-email-python/